# Ubuntu boots to black screen

Tags: boot, screen

I installed Ubuntu a couple of days back. I have an Asus K3SV laptop (nvidia optimus sigh) and Im triple booting ubuntu, fedora and windows.

Now when Im booting Ubuntu, during the boot process the screen turns off and nothing happens. Its not just a black screen, the screen is basically off, and the processor LED also stops blinking.

I tried booting it using the parameters a number of other posts suggest, replacing quiet splash with verbose nomodset.

During the display of all the messages, ubuntu halts only for a couple of seconds to display 'over-current condition on port 3' and 'over-current condition on port 4'

It only lasts a couple of second after which it zooms past a couple of messages and the screen turns off. The last few messages, are a couple of 'ahc1' and two messages of 'SATA...' and the a couple of 'DUMMY'

Fedora and windows works fine, just mentioning it.

Comment: How about recovery mode? Does work? Try pressing `shift` key when before grub appears. Try running some other boot options than the default.

Comment: Ive tried the recovery mode, which takes me to an area where i can login. after i login with my username and password, a minute later or so the screen turns blank again

Comment: That seems quite wierd. Which version of Ubuntu do you have installed? Is it an option for you to try for example previous one like 12.04 LTS and install it instead the existing one?